# Mutex Lock (JS) Shared between multiple tabs of a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, mutex

Is there any way for two tabs within a browser to share a Mutex (in JavaScript)?

I am working on a web-app using node.js & socket.io, and I want the various tabs to share a single connection with the server. The so-called 'leader' tab is the only one that maintains the connection, while messages to the rest of them are all relayed via this one. Right now, I'm using a leader election algorithm to choose the leader, but given that it takes a second or two to re-elect a new leader if the current one goes down, I wonder if there is a better method to do the same.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker), which is a convenient way to share this sort of work between n different tabs. SharedWorker also disqualifies you from [bfcache](https://web.dev/bfcache/) though

Answer (score 8):

This has essentially been added to browsers, and it's called the [Web Locks API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Locks_API).

A leader election is as simple as acquiring an exclusive lock of a given name, then holding it however long you wish.

```javascript
let abdicate; // function that releases the lock

navigator.locks.request("takemetoyourleader", lock => {
    console.log("wow I just won the election");

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        abdicate = resolve;
    });
});
```

By returning a Promise that doesn't resolve, the lock is held indefinitely. When the tab holding the lock is closed, the lock will automatically be released, and a different tab of the same origin can obtain it instead.

Note that holding a lock will disqualify your site from using the [bfcache](https://web.dev/bfcache/), so you might want to implement pagehide/pageshow listeners to manually release/retake this lock.

Answer (score 2):

There are various libraries that either try to solve the problem of locking directly or provide message passing between tabs, which you could use as a building block.
Check out:

- https://github.com/tejacques/crosstab
- https://github.com/slimjack/IWC
- https://github.com/nodeca/tabex
- http://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/
- https://github.com/jitbit/TabUtils